# Centering text Between Two other Divs in a Header

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNfB8.jpg)

I'm trying to center the h4 between the two divs.  I would like this to be static and stay in the same place regardless of the resolution.  The icon and form do not move, but the h4 text does.  How can I make this sit in one spot and not move?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>21st Century Dad</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/logo-small.png">

</head>

<body>

<header>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#26ADE4; float:right; font:14px 'Kanit',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 20px; text-align:center; border-radius:20px; width:250px;}
    h4{text-align:center;clear:both; position:absolute; top:80px; right:600px; font-size:42px; font-weight:bold; color:#26ADE4;}/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>

<!-- Header Information -->
<h4>21st Century Dad</h4>
<div id="header-content">
<a href="../index.php"> <img src="../images/logo-big.png" alt="21st Century Dad" height="110" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:40px;" /> </a>

<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//fb.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=48be460d4492dcbdd2828666e&amp;id=f7d2ed069d" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
Sign up for our newsletter!
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk"></span></div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_48be460d4492dcbdd2828666e_f7d2ed069d" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="background-color:#D1E751; font:14px 'Kanit',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin-top:4px; border-radius:5px; border-color:#D1E751; "></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<!--<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script> -->

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
</div></header>

<nav>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<!--Navigation Information-->

<ul>
    <li><a href="../about/index.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="../diy-projects/index.php">DIY Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="../dad-tech.php">Dad Tech</a></li>
    <li><a href="../kid-stuff/index.php">Kid Stuff</a></li>
    <li><a href="../ask-a-dad/index.php">Ask a Dad</a></li>
    <li><a href="../dad-jokes.php">Dad Jokes</a></li>
</ul></nav>

<div id="wrapper">
<main>

<div class = "container">
<div class = "blocks">
<h1>What's New with Dad?</h1>
<a href="about/index.php"><img src="images/whatsnew.png" alt="About Me Picture" style="border:1px solid #000;"></a>
</div>
<div class = "blocks">
<h1>DIY Project of the Week</h1>
<a href="diy-projects/index.php"><img src="images/diyproject.jpg" alt="DIY Project Picture" style="border:1px solid #000;"></a>
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Dad Gadget of the Week</h1>
<a href="dad-tech.php"><img src="images/dadgadget.jpg" alt="Dad Gadget of the Week Picture" style="border:1px solid #000;"></a>
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Activity / Meal of the Week</h1>
<a href="kid-stuff/index.php"><img src="images/dadactivity.jpg" alt="Kid Activity & Meal of the Week" style="border:1px solid #000;"></a>
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Dad Q & A of the Week</h1>
<a href="ask-a-dad/index.php"><img src="images/askadad.png" alt="Dad Q & A of the Week" style="border:1px solid #000;"></a>
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Dad Joke of the Week</h1>
<a href="dad-jokes.php"><img src="images/dadjokes.jpg" alt="Dad Joke of the Week" style="border:1px solid #000;"></a>
</div>
</div><!-- end container -->


</main>

<footer>  
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<body link="#FFFFFF">

<div id="footer">
         <p class="left">
        <a href="mailto:bahrn@my.uwstout.edu">E-mail 21st Century Dad</a>

        <p class="right">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"> 
        <img src="../images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Logo"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/"> 
        <img src="../images/snapchat.png" alt="Snapchat Logo"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"> 
        <img src="../images/instagram.png" alt="Instagram Logo"/></a>

         <p class="centered">
        &copy; Copyright 2017 21st Century Dad

</div></footer>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The style for the h4 is in the head.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and create a snippet demonstrating your issue, with the style you currently using?

Comment: You say "the two divs", so which two of the divs are we talking about here?

Comment: instead of right, use left and it will always stay in that spot.  by using right, when the screen is resized, it means the amount of space from the right changes which is why it is moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `left: 0; right: 0` for `h4`. that will fix it

What you have done is, placed `h4` tag in absolute position and used some fixed position from right. If you use the above code, it will make the element `h4` 100% width since right and left is 0 which is origin and you've already center aligned the text so it will always be center relative to the parent.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If your `h4` is absolute positioned you can either give it a fixed width and set the `left` and `right` to 0 and `margin: auto;`, or you can give it `width: 100%;` and `text-align: center;` I don't know why you are absolutely positioning them but that's up to you

```
h4 {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```
h4 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I might have misunderstood your question though, if you want to position it in the center of two other elements, wrap them all in a container and use flexbox:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div-1"></div>
    <h4>Hey</h4>
    <div class="div-2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```